# Can I wrap the MaterialApp widget with the Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to create an app with provider. I wrapped MaterialApp widget with the ChangeNotifierProvider and the app works and I can use the provider as it intended to do. I need to know is it okay to do so and will i face any problems?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<BaseModel>(
        builder: (context) =>
            BaseModel(loading: false, title: "Title", isLoggedIn: false),
        child: MaterialApp(
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                "/home": (BuildContext context) => Home(),
                "/signIn": (BuildContext context) => SignIn()
            },
            initialRoute: "/signIn",
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
                // is not restarted.
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: SignIn()),
    );
```

In all the sample codes they use Provider under "home" in MaterialApp widget. I used MaterialApp inside the provider.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is totally fine. There's no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a better solution to use provider pattern with named routing?

Comment: I've been searching the solution whole days but no luck