# Where in the tree to wrap widget with Provider to use the Provider for maintaining state throughout an app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

My app has a simple home page screen

```
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {}
```

and two additional screens. Users are routed to the additional screens with code like

```
Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (BuildContext context) => Page2(),
       ),
```

and

```
Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Page3(),
       ),
```

`Page2()` has a simple stopwatch which I implement with a Provider. I want to add the identical stopwatch code to `Page3()`. I would think `StartPage()` is further up the "tree" than `Page2()` and `Page3()`, and that if I wrap `StartPage`'s build method with a Provider (along with Consumer widget code inside the relevant classes)

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<StopWatchProvider>(
      create: (context) => StopWatchProvider(),
      child: Scaffold()
```

then the stopwatch should work as expected in both `Page2()` and `Page3()` (supported by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691515/can-i-wrap-the-materialapp-widget-with-the-provider)). But this throws an error about being unable to find a Provider and, instead, I need to wrap builders for `Page2()` and `Page3()` with a Provider.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping `MaterialApp` with your `Provider()`?

Comment: I know this is going to make me sound stupid, but I've tried wrapping so many things now that I've forgotten. Should I wrap `MaterialApp`? (Just this minute I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045822/navigator-push-error-could-not-find-the-correct-provider-above-this-consumer?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, that asures you that you can access that provider everywhere in your app. If that's what you need, go for it

Comment: Yup, that did it :-) ... I'm still unsure why my original code didn't work, but you definitely solved the issue.